# No definition found for class:'yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.repository.BBCRepository' & qualifier:'bbcModules'. Check your definitions?

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, koin

I am developing news android app and I have implemented Koin modules but I am getting the following exception

```
executor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:147)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.repository.BBCRepository' & qualifier:'bbcModules'. Check your definitions!
 at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:247)
 at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:216)
 at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:181)
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.module.BbcModulesKt$bbcModules$1$2.invoke(bbcModules.kt:16)
 at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.module.BbcModulesKt$bbcModules$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
 at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
 ... 48 more
```

below my bbcModules.kt where  I have implemented BBCSportViewModel logic

```
val bbcModules = module {
    factory(named("bbcModules")) { (BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get())) }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of BBCRepository

    viewModel { BBCSportViewModel(bbcRepository = get(named("bbcModules")))

    }


}
```

below BBCRepository.kt

```
interface BBCRepository {
    // Suspend is used to await the result from Deferred
    suspend fun getBBCList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
}


@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class BBCRepositoryImpl(private val bbcsportNewsApi: SportNewsInterface) : BBCRepository {
    override suspend fun getBBCList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>> {

        return try {
            val result = bbcsportNewsApi.getBBCSport().body()!!.articles
            UseCaseResult.Success(result)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake what I have to fix exception I have followed many StackOverflow answer it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace says that no definition for **BBCRepository** was found.

In your koin module you have a factory of `BBCRepositoryImpl` and not `BBCRepository`:

```
factory(named("bbcModules")) {
   (BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get())) 
}
```

In order for it to work, you should make sure you are providing the interface in koin with:

```
factory<BBCRepository>(named("bbcModules")) { 
    BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get())
}
```

or

```
factory(named("bbcModules")) {
 (BBCRepositoryImpl(bbcsportNewsApi = get())) as BBCRepository 
}
```

Comment: you answer a bit incorrect can you help me to correct it

Comment: I changed the second snippet, does it work for you?